# In Windows what's the difference between logging in via IP Address and by File Share?

Tags: windows, network-share, ip-address, unc

I have two users on my QNAP NAS, one with admin privileges and one with read only. If I log into the file share in Windows File Explorer via `\\192.168.1.xxx` I enter my credentials for read only and get read only access. Now I open another File Explorer window along side the first and log in via `\\FileShare` and I get the credential screen again! I log in as admin and am now logged in as both side by side. If I try and create a new folder in the first window (read only user privileges), it won't let me do it. But if I create a new folder in the other window (Admin privileges) it lets me!

What on earth is going on here? It seems that Windows uses different privileges/credentials for file shares depending on how they are represented (share name vs IP address).

Can someone please explain how this is possible?

Comment: Setting aside that QNAP may have its own quirks... What you wrote sounds like you provided different credentials to each session. One has user creds that are read only, one has admin creds that are writable. Sounds normal to me.

Comment: By "\FileShare" do you actually mean `\\NASHostName`, against `\\192.168.1.xx`?

Comment: Open a cmd prompt, type `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`. Does it show you 2 entries for your QNAP?

Comment: It sounds like Windows tracks sessions based on what you typed in/used to create the session. If it were to treat them the same, it would probably need to resolve the servers names to IP addresses. They likely have done it this way to increase flexibility. Think of multiple servers hosting the same share for redundancy or performance reasons (something like Windows DFS). This appears to be a feature of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue appear when you log in \192.168.x.x using admin credentials? If so, it probably caused by the permission configuration you have on QNAP side.

Check the permissions for local admin and other groups. Ensure you have added your account to administrators group.
https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/advanced-folder-permissions-on-qnap-nas